# How to bubble sort an array of integers while showing steps in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, visual-studio, bubble-sort

C# Visual Studio - Windows Form Application

I am trying to create a program that bubble sorts a seeded array of integers and shows each step line by line. The program does just that but I would like it to stop writing the array after it is fully sorted. For example an array of {1, 4, 5, 2, 6} would display like this:

```
          1  4  5  2  6
          1  4  2  5  6
          1  2  4  5  6
          1  2  4  5  6
          1  2  4  5  6
```

I want it to cut off after the third line. Here is the current code:

```
    int[] randArray = new int[5];
    private void btnLotto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        fillArray();
        sortArray();
    }
    private void fillArray() {
        Random random = new Random(int.Parse(txtSeed.Text));
        for (int i = 0; i < randArray.Length; i++) {
            int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 51);
            randArray[i] = randomNumber;
        }
    }
    private void displayArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < randArray.Length; i++) {
            txtLotto.AppendText(randArray[i].ToString().PadRight(3));
        }
        txtLotto.AppendText("\r\n");
    }
    private void sortArray() {
        txtLotto.Text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < randArray.Length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < randArray.Length - 1; j++) {
                if (randArray[j] > randArray[j + 1]) {
                    swap(ref randArray[j], ref randArray[j + 1]);
                }
            }
                displayArray();
        }
    }
    private void swap(ref int a, ref int b) {
        int tempA = a;
        a = b;
        b = tempA;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a student exercise, am I right? In your `sortArray()` function, your first `for` loop should test if the array is already sorted and do a `break` in that case.

Comment: Vyrira, yes it is a student exercise. I'm not sure how to test if it's already sorted.

Comment: If it's not at least as cool as [this](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html) I'll be disappointed.

Comment: @TylerArnett - you can test that it's already sorted by comparing each number with its neighbor; if the neighbor is smaller, it's not sorted yet.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to display once for each run through the outer loop, but you don't want to display if nothing changed, you can set a flag for that and only display when appropriate.

```
bool swapped = false;
for (int i = 0; i < randArray.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < randArray.Length - 1; j++) {
        if (randArray[j] > randArray[j + 1]) {
            swap(ref randArray[j], ref randArray[j + 1]);
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
    if (swapped) {
        displayArray();
    }
}
```

---

**Original:**

I'd modify the code so it does a display immediately after a swap:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randArray.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < randArray.Length - 1; j++) {
        if (randArray[j] > randArray[j + 1]) {
            swap(ref randArray[j], ref randArray[j + 1]);
            displayArray(); // Moved from outer for loop
        }
    }
}
```

That way it only re-displays if a swap occurred.

Comment: Adam V, now the code doesn't repeat the last line, but rather takes more than 5 steps to complete. It doesn't exactly bubble sort in order anymore. For example, the array {31, 39, 41, 28, 11} sorts in 8 because it only does 1 swap per execution of the loop. It won't swap 41 with 28 then with 11. It takes 2 steps to do that.

Comment: @TylerArnett Not really sure what you mean. This will display the new array after every sort. If you want to see the 'first line' (AKA the unsorted list), simply call `displayArray()` before `sortArray()`. This answer won't change the behaviour of the sort at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store if you make any swaps in the inner sorting loop. If you don't make any changes the list is sorted and you can exit.

```
displayArray();
for (int i = 0; i < randArray.Length; i++) {
        bool changed=false;
        for (int j = 0; j < randArray.Length - 1; j++) {
            if (randArray[j] > randArray[j + 1]) {
                swap(ref randArray[j], ref randArray[j + 1]);
                changed=true;
            }
        }            
        if(changed)
            displayArray();
        else
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Nothing changed? That's odd, When I tested it just now, the final line was displayed twice. Otherwise everything was as wanted.